# Combining values of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy guys, i have a form with multiple inputs and dropdowns and depending on the user selection the final result is something like this:

```
var optionVariants = [
    {
       attribute: {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Color'
    },
       values: ['red', 'green']
    },
    {
       attribute: {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Size'
    },
       values: ['small', 'medium', 'large']
    }
];
```

All i want is to loop trough the object and make a new object that will look like this:

```
        var newObject = [
            {
                attributes: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color',
                        value: 'red'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size',
                        value: 'small'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                attributes: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color',
                        value: 'red'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size',
                        value: 'medium'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                attributes: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color',
                        value: 'red'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size',
                        value: 'large'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                attributes: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color',
                        value: 'green'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size',
                        value: 'small'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                attributes: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color',
                        value: 'green'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size',
                        value: 'medium'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                attributes: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color',
                        value: 'green'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size',
                        value: 'large'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

I have tried to create empty arrays, push items in them, loop trough them but i cannot find the correct solution to group them like i want.

I'm not a javascript expert and i'm still learning so be gentle with me :D

This is what i have tried:

```
var option_groups = [
    ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
    ["S", "M", "L"],
    ["Cotton", "Silk"]
];

var variants = [];
var combos = [];
var nnew = [];
var variant = [];
var option = "";
var ttmp = []
var combo = [];

if (option_groups.length > 1) {
    for (var i in option_groups[0]) {
        variants.push([option_groups[0][i]]);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < option_groups.length; i++) {
        combos = [];

        for (var j in variants) {
            variant = variants[j];
            nnew = [];

            for (var x in option_groups[i]) {
                option = option_groups[i][x];
                ttmp = [];
                for (var d in variant) {
                    ttmp.push(variant[d]);
                }
                ttmp.push(option);
                nnew.push(ttmp);
            }

            combos.push(nnew);
        }
        variants = [];
        for (var y in combos) {
            combo = combos[y];
            for (var z in combo) {
                variants.push(combo[z]);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(variants);
}
```

Comment: anything you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var optionVariants = [
    {
        attribute: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Color'
        },
        values: ['red', 'green']
    },
    {
        attribute: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Size'
        },
        values: ['small', 'medium', 'large']
    }
];

var firstObjectValues = optionVariants[0]['values'];
var secondObjectValues = optionVariants[1]['values'];
var firstObjectValuesAmount = firstObjectValues.length;
var secondObjectValuesAmount = secondObjectValues.length;
var newObject = [];

for (var i = 0; i < firstObjectValuesAmount; i++) {
    
    for (var j = 0; j < secondObjectValuesAmount; j++) {
        var obj1 = {};
        obj1.id = optionVariants[0]['attribute'].id;
        obj1.name = optionVariants[0]['attribute'].name;
        obj1.value = optionVariants[0]['values'][i];

        var obj2 = {};
        obj2.id = optionVariants[1]['attribute'].id;
        obj2.name = optionVariants[1]['attribute'].name;
        obj2.value = optionVariants[1]['values'][j];

        var finalObj = {
            attributes: [obj1, obj2]
        };

        newObject.push(finalObj);
    }
    
}

console.log(newObject);
```

**That's it!**

Comment: We don't know how many variants are in optionVariants...could be 2, 3 8, 10 etc....

Comment: You didn't tell us about this issue

Comment: So you need one more cycle to fix this issue based on my code

Comment: So anyway you have to use so many nested loops as many optionVariants you have. For example for 5 optionVariants - 5 nested loops.

Comment: So use recursion

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it...it is in angular because this is what my projects uses but it should be easy to convert it in plain if somebody needs it.

The object or the data tha comes from user input is like this:

```
$scope.optionVariants = [
                {
                    attribute: {
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Color'
                    },
                    values: ['red']
                },
                {
                    attribute: {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Size'
                    },
                    values: ['small', 'medium']
                },
                {
                    attribute: {
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Material'
                    },
                    values: ['cotton']
                },
                {
                    attribute: {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'Pictures'
                    },
                    values: ['single']
                },
                {
                    attribute: {
                        id: 5,
                        name: 'Lamp'
                    },
                    values: ['led', 'normal']
                }
            ];
```

The user form has 2 fields, a select option for selecting the Attribute like color, size, material etc. and a text filed that acts as a tag input where the user passes values separated by comma.

In the angular controller we do like this:

```
$scope.namedAttributes = [];
    $scope.attributesChanged = function (index) {
        var variants = [];
        var combos = [];
        var nnew = [];
        var variant = [];
        var option = "";
        var ttmp = [];
        var combo = [];

        angular.forEach($scope.optionVariants[0].values, function (element, index) {
            variants.push([element]);
        });

        for (var i = 1; i < $scope.optionVariants.length; i++) {
            combos = [];

            angular.forEach(variants, function (element, index) {
                variant = element;
                nnew = [];

                angular.forEach($scope.optionVariants[i].values, function (element, index) {
                    option = element;

                    ttmp = [];
                    variant.forEach(function (element) {
                        ttmp.push(element);
                    });

                    ttmp.push(option);
                    nnew.push(ttmp);
                });

                combos.push(nnew);
            });

            variants = [];
            angular.forEach(combos, function (element, index) {
                combo = element;
                combo.forEach(function (element) {
                    variants.push(element);
                });
            });
        }

        $scope.namedAttributes = [];
        angular.forEach(variants, function (element, index) {
            var attributes = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                attributes.push({
                    id: $scope.optionVariants[i].attribute.id,
                    name: $scope.optionVariants[i].attribute.name,
                    value: element[i]
                });
            }

            $scope.namedAttributes.push({
                attributes: attributes
            });
        });
    };
```

So at the end, $scope.namedAttributes translates to this:

```
[
                {
                    attributes: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'Color',
                            value: 'red'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: 'Size',
                            value: 'small'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: 'Material',
                            value: 'cotton'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            name: 'Pictures',
                            value: 'single'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            name: 'Lamp',
                            value: 'led'
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    attributes: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'Color',
                            value: 'red'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: 'Size',
                            value: 'small'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: 'Material',
                            value: 'cotton'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            name: 'Pictures',
                            value: 'single'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            name: 'Lamp',
                            value: 'normal'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```